# Why is java not reading the Content-length response header?

Tags: java, networking, web, content-length

I have the following code to read the content-length response header of the resource pointed by the following url but this code doesn't read the content length and returns -1. I am wondering why.

```
 try{


String song_url = "https://doc-0c-6o-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/mtop3kcd4g9holc81thpce8mmck772ja/10to2su90o897bl390ojai9srph2fmvq/1407182400000/15635312626103908265/15635312626103908265/0B8CobC-HnuclMm5sUnVpOW13eEk?e=download&h=16653014193614665626&nonce=5beqd4pl58o30&user=15635312626103908265&hash=qbqjjhkrpco10b8ggu7ko5qa5c64th2m";


                    URL web = new URL(song_url);

                    con1 = web.openConnection();

                     total_size = con1.getContentLength();

                    ((HttpURLConnection)con1).disconnect();

                    return total_size;

                }
                catch(Exception e){

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                ((HttpURLConnection)con1).disconnect();
```

Now, the strange thing is if you just paste this url in the browser

https://doc-0c-6o-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/mtop3kcd4g9holc81thpce8mmck772ja/10to2su90o897bl390ojai9srph2fmvq/1407182400000/15635312626103908265/15635312626103908265/0B8CobC-HnuclMm5sUnVpOW13eEk?e=download&h=16653014193614665626&nonce=5beqd4pl58o30&user=15635312626103908265&hash=qbqjjhkrpco10b8ggu7ko5qa5c64th2m

and then under inspect element > network in google chrome then you will see that the browser reads the content length correctly.

content-length:79476777

But why is the java code failing to read the content-length? Is this a problem with the library i am using? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You'll have to `con1.connect()` before getting the content length.

Comment: sorry it is still returning -1

Comment: If the server uses HTTP Chunking, then there is no way you can access the content length until you have read all the bytes (which is the point: to allow unspecified content length, and thus enable advanced use cases, such as on the fly gzipping). ContentLength is not reliable, generally speaking, over HTTP.

Comment: but the browser shows that it is returning content-length if you follow this step in chrome "inspect element > network"

Comment: That's why it's just a comment and not an answer I provided. Please not your link is password protected, so we can not inspect further. One can only guess what chrome does : calculate content length afterwards ? Send a slightly different request (HTTP 1.0 ?) that disables chunking on the server side... One can only guess right now.

Comment: This is strange...when you hit the url in browser and read the response headers it looks like content-length:79476777
content-type:video/mp4 but when i print the content type using the code above and System.out.println(((HttpURLConnection)con1).getContentType()); then it prints text/html; charset=UTF-8 so that explains the size...it is returning not a video file but a text/html file. isnt it?

Comment: It's because your resource is password protected. Your Java client is redirected to the HTML login page of google.

Comment: hmm..can you access the link above? because i logged out and still can access the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be because the server isn't sending a Content-length header. There are a least two other ways it can convey the length:

1. By closing the socket after sending the request body. In HTTP 1.1 I think this would have to be accompanied by a 'Connection: close ' header. In this case the content length is the length of the body, and you have to read it all to measure it.
2. By using chunked transfer encoding. In this case the content length is the sum of the lengths of the chunks. Again you would have to read it all to determine the length.

Comment: I think the server is sending the content-length header. Like i have mentioned in the post above "and then under inspect element > network in google chrome then you will see that the browser reads the content length correctly"

Comment: the browser shows the content-length header in the response fields.

Comment: As @GPI points out above, that's not the page your Java client is reading. It is reading a login page which evidently is sent without a Content-length header.

Comment: but if you can access the link above then i don't think it is redirecting to login page.

Comment: the link is made public so anyone should be able to access it without authentication.

Comment: You can think what you like, but until you try reading the content with your client and posting enough of it here to prove the point, it is all just speculation on your part. At the moment ***I*** get a login screen. QED

Comment: oh..really? how come i dont get the login screen even after logging out of gmail. so confused....

Comment: Cookies? It's irrelevant why. I've answered your question.

Comment: ok i will look into it more but thanks for your efforts. I will accept your answer.